# First order partial differential equation - how to finish the solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have problems solving this simple pde. I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

$$yu_x - u_y = y, \ \ \ u(x,0 ) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Here is how I do it. The equation is equivalent to this one:

$$\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-1} = \frac{du}{y}$$

So $\frac{dx}{y} = - dy, \ \ dx=du$

This means that $dx = -ydy$ and $u = x+ C$

So $x + C' = - \frac{y^2}{2} $ and $u = x+C$

This above gives us an  integral curve $F(x,y) = - x - \frac{y^2}{2}$ of $yu_x - u_y=0$, but not of the main pde.

If we plug $F(x,0) = -x$, we get $u(x,0) = - \frac{1}{F(x,0)}$, so $u(x,y) = - \frac{1}{F(x,y)} = \frac{1}{x+ \frac{y^2}{2}}$, which is not the solution.

Could you help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method of characteristics.

First, reparameterise your curve letting

$$x \to x(s) \\
y \to y(s)$$

Hence you have

$$u = u(x(s), y(s))$$

Taking the total derivative wrt to $s$

$$\begin{align}
\implies \frac{d}{ds} u &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{ds} \\
&= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot y + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \cdot (-1) \\
&= y \\
\end{align}$$

Equating, we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{ds} &= -1 \\
\implies dy &= -ds \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= y \\
\implies \frac{dx}{-dy} &= y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) \\
\frac{du}{ds} &= y \\
\implies \frac{du}{-dy} &= y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3) \\
\end{align}$$

Solving

$$\begin{align}
(2) \implies x(s) &= \frac{-y^{2}}{2} + x_{0} \\
(3) \implies u(x, y) &= \frac{-y^{2}}{2} + f(x_0) \\
&= \frac{-y^{2}}{2} + f \bigg(x + \frac{y^{2}}{2} \bigg) \ \ \ \ \ \ (4) \\
\end{align}$$

Using our initial condition

$$\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= f(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \\
\implies f \bigg(x + \frac{y^{2}}{2} \bigg) &=  \frac{1}{x + \frac{y^{2}}{2}} \\
\end{align}$$

Substituting into $(4)$, we find

$$u(x, y) = \frac{-y^{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{y^{2}}{2}}$$

You can check by differentiation that this satisfies the PDE and initial condition.

Comment: If you need anymore help, just post below this comment. Also, if you could accept and upvote this answer, that would be great.

Comment: No, everything is clear. Thank you :)